# Vb.net image mask making smooth along the edges

Tags: vb.net, image, mask, antialiasing

Hey all i am trying to get my images to look nice and smooth (antialiasing) from using a mask in order to make the round image as you see below:

[image: round image]

The original image looks like this:

[image: org image]

The mask for the image above looks like this (the red being the mask color to take out):

[image: mask image]

It works but it gives me those not-so-nice jagged edges around it. The mask is an .png and also the image itself is a .png.

The code i use to make the mask is this:

```
picNextTopic1.Image = Image.FromStream(wc.OpenRead(anAPI.wallOrgPostImage(keying).Replace("{width}", "50").Replace("{height}", "50"))) 'Download the image from the website.                  
picNextTopic1.Image = ApplyMask(New Bitmap(picNextTopic1.Image), New Bitmap(My.Resources.mask), Color.Red) 'Apply mask to the downloaded image above.
```

The ApplyMask function is this:

```
Public Function ApplyMask(ByVal bImg As Bitmap, ByVal bMask As Bitmap, ByVal maskColor As Color) As Image
    Dim wImg As Integer = bImg.Width
    Dim hImg As Integer = bImg.Height
    Dim wMask As Integer = bMask.Width
    Dim hMask As Integer = bMask.Height
    Dim intMask As Integer = maskColor.ToArgb
    Dim intTransparent As Integer = Color.Transparent.ToArgb

    Using fpImg As New FastPix(bImg)
        Using fpMask As New FastPix(bMask)
            Dim pixelsImg = fpImg.PixelArray
            Dim pixelsMask = fpMask.PixelArray

            For y As Integer = 0 To Math.Min(hImg, hMask) - 1
                For x As Integer = 0 To Math.Min(wImg, wMask) - 1
                    Dim iImg As Integer = (y * wImg) + x
                    Dim iMask As Integer = (y * wMask) + x

                    If pixelsMask(iMask) = intMask Then
                        pixelsImg(iImg) = intTransparent
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End Using
    End Using

    Return bImg
End Function
```

Which uses **FastPix** found [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=586709).

Any help to smooth this out would be great! Thanks!

**UPDATE**
code for transparent form that i have:

```
Public Sub InitializeMyForm()
    BackColor = Color.Plum
    TransparencyKey = BackColor
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of a binary mask, you could make an alpha mask which has a smooth transition between unmasked and masked.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with this, I did manage to make a smooth image this way using a TextureBrush:

```
Dim profile As Image = Image.FromFile("c:\...\profile.png")

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
  e.Graphics.Clear(Color.SteelBlue)
  e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
  Using tb As New TextureBrush(profile)
    tb.TranslateTransform(120, 64)
    Using p As New GraphicsPath
      p.AddEllipse(120, 64, profile.Width, profile.Width)
      e.Graphics.FillPath(tb, p)
    End Using
  End Using
  MyBase.OnPaint(e)
End Sub
```

The TranslateTransform and the AddEllipse location use the same point information in order to "center" the texture brush appropriately.

The result:

[image]

Comment: Do you get the same outcome even if the form window itself is transparent like mine is?

Comment: And also from your example it seems you are only using 1 image instead of a mask?

Comment: @StealthRT Correct.  No need for the mask.  A transparent background won't really work since you need a background to *alias* with.  You would have to copy the area of the source before applying my example.

Comment: Yeah thats what i figured... but i need the background form to be transparent. :o/

Comment: I can do this in WPF just fine but most of my code i have right now wont work within a WPF - just a Windows form app.

Comment: @StealthRT You can always try the [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) control.